# Grails and Google App Engine - Should I use them together?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, grails

I've been playing around with Grails and Google App Engine for a day or so using Eclipse+STS+Google plugin and I've been running into a number of roadblocks.

However, I'm not sure if this is just lack of experience with them on my part or if the Grails+GAE support is just not mature enough. Should I switch to Java+GAE until the Grails support matures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't go for it. It needs more time to mature.

**The website itself states that the plugin is bugged.**

> Bugs
>
> It is true that there are some bugs
>   with this plugin, but most have a
>   solution at this time.
>
> Example: The "DataNucleus Enhancer
>   prevents application from building on
>   Windows OS due to path length
>   exceeding max path length on Windows."
>
> However, there is a work-around for Windows and this wont stop use of the
>   plugin.

**Some annoying bugs have not been fixed:**

- on windows, [killing the grails app-engine run process leaves an orphan java process](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-1168), so every time, you have to manually end the java process,
- [flash.message is broken on GAE](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-1182),
- [Cannot run integration tests with GAE/GORM-JPA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-1467).

If you feel like spending time debugging the plugin, writing and testing workarounds, go for it. Still, you wouldn't be safe from critical/blocker issues which will make you MAAAD!

If you really want to work on App-Engine, [using Eclipse and the Google Plugin for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse.html) seems the easiest and most efficient method.

Comment: I saw the comment, "However, there is a work-around for Windows and this wont stop use of the plugin." and was pretty frustrated that the solution appears to be known but isn't shared. 

I ended up building a POM to do Java+GAE using Google's maven plugin. It works quite well so I'm not actually using the Google Eclipse plugin at the moment. I also noticed the orphan java process happens when I do gae:run for debugging as well with Java/Maven so maybe that is not specific to Grails.

Comment: Grails is "Rapid", "Dynamic" and "Robust" but everything just goes away with the GAE plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [Gaelyk](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-javadev2-6/?ca=dgr-jw22Gaelyk&S_TACT=105AGX59&S_CMP=grjw22) lightweight Groovy implementation and web framework meant to be used on GAE.

Comment: The Gaelyk site says, "At the time of the creation of the project, Grails was not yet ported to App Engine, and we felt a streamlined toolkit would be interesting. For bigger applications, you should be considering Grails though..." It sounds like they are suggesting Grails for a larger application.

Comment: You can always use Amazon's EC2 to deploy your Grails apps.

http://chris-richardson.blog-city.com/grails_plugin_for_deploying_to_amazon_ec2.htm

Comment: I don't want to pay for Amazon EC2 and I believe CloudFoundry is also going to require paying at some point in the future as well. That was my reason for wanting to use GAE.

Answer (score 0):

Grails on App Engine is definitely maturing with each new release (of Grails and the App Engine plugin). If you post questions regarding your particular road blocks I'm sure people will be able to help you. There are quite a few public Grails/GAE sites out there now.

As Boris posted, Gaelyk is a good lightweight alternative for simpler sites.

Comment: Posted a few of them:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128569/grails-class-org-grails-tomcat-tomcatloader-was-not-found-in-the-classpath
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128544/grails-warnings-errors-during-run-app

Comment: @leebutts Except grails nabble forum (http://old.nabble.com/grails---user-f11861.html), what are the other <quote>"Grails/GAE sites out there now"</quote> ?

Comment: Found these via Google (a couple seem to down though!)

http://groovytweets.appspot.com
http://petclinic-grails.appspot.com (demo app from Graeme Rocher, Grails lead)
http://mindhackme.appspot.com/
http://maxieduncan.appspot.com/